# Parachain blocknumber/times are hard to approximate, how can we unlock balances for crowdloan participants in an accurate way?

Tags: parachain

We are a newly born Kusama parachain (still controlled by sudo), and we need to lock 70% of all KSM crowdloan participant balances into a wallet.

We are using Vesting (actually Scheduler pallet) which make batched calls to reserve (70% of the) balances. Then we need to unlock 70% by the end of the 48 week parachain slot period.

Currently our block times range from 12s to 36s. So it is very hard to estimate what block number 48 weeks will be.

1. What is the best way to accurately get closest to 48 weeks?
2. How do we regulate parachain blocktimes?
3. Is there anyway we can use Kusama blocknumber, perhaps there is a pallet that is leveraging this?
4. What's the best most precedent example of other projects doing this?

Comment: Just an idea, but you could probably hook up your vesting pallet to the relay chain block number, which is quite consistent, rather than your local block number. This would also be a 1:1 mapping with your parachain slot period, which is defined by relay chain blocks.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. Looks like we need to fork the scheduler pallet and add relay block number to the public method. Does that sound the best way? Are you aware of any other parachains who (must) have done this. I checked Acala, but can’t quite understand the orml_vesting pallet.